# Spring MVC : using wildcards in <mvc:resources>

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm implementing a cache busting system for a Spring MVC application.

For this system to work, I have to strip the "cache busting code" from a given url. Let's say my generated cache busting code is "123" and I have a .css url that is: **/public-123/css/style.css**. In this example, I want **/public/css/style.css** to be succesfully called (*-123* must be stripped).

This works in my "mvc-config.xml" context file:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/public-123/**" location="/public/" />
```

But I would also like *any* cache busting code to work, even if it's not the current one. For example, I would also like **/public-456/css/style.css** to reach the style.css file.

If I try to add another wildcard to the mapping:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/public-*/**" location="/public/" />
```

It doesn't work! I receive a 404....

How could I specify the "mapping" attribute so any code after the "public-" part is well managed?

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this is to use Spring EL, as shown in the [Spring docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-static-resources):

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources-#{applicationProps['application.version']}/**" location="/public-resources/"/>
```

You could probably store the "123" part in a properties file so it only gets set once. E.g. via [property-placeholder](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer):

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:myApp.properties"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources-${cache.code}/**" location="/public-resources/"/>
```

This has the advantage of being able to read this code in your JSP pages (to generate links) via the same properties value.

Comment: Thanks nickdos, but this is what I'm already using actually! I simplified the code to ask the question on SO. What I really want is _any_ code to be stripped, not just a specific one that would be defined in a properties file.

Comment: Fair enough. Have you turned on DEBUG level logging for org.springframework, it might report more info on what is happening. I think you're going to have to delve into the Spring code and see why the internal * is not being caught. You might have to extend one of the classes to handle the internal "*" yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working by manually defining the `ResourceHttpRequestHandler` to handle assets that are located on the filesystem alongside the `<mvc:resources />` tag:

```
<bean id="assetsResourceHandler" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler">
  <property name="locations">
    <list>
      <bean class="org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource">
        <constructor-arg value="file:#{applicationProps['assets.basedir']}"></constructor-arg>
      </bean>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: What is the name of your properties file?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're doing this to achieve cache busting for your static resources.

In the meantime, [Spring 4.1 has dedicated features for this](https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/24/spring-framework-4-1-handling-static-web-resources), so you can remove a lot of that custom configuration.

Something like this:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/public/**" location="/public/"/>
  <mvc:resource-chain resource-cache="true">
    <mvc:resolvers>
      <mvc:version-resolver>
        <mvc:content-version-strategy patterns="/**"/>
      </mvc:version-resolver>
    </mvc:resolvers>
  </mvc:resource-chain>
</mvc:resources>
```