# How to use variables in static content path in spring-servlet.xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, configuration

I want to make my asset folder base dependent on version to prevent caching issues for my users. I'm currently using spring with a spring-servlet.xml to configure my static routes.

This is my current configuration

```
 <!-- Static routes -->
  <mvc:resources mapping="/assets/**" location="/assets/" cache-period="0" />
  <mvc:resources mapping="/img/**" location="/assets/img/"  cache-period="31556926" />
  <mvc:resources location="/assets/img/favicon.ico" mapping="/favicon.ico" />
```

I would like to use something like this but I don't know how to configure this.

```
 <!-- Static routes -->
  <mvc:resources mapping="/assets/${version}/**" location="/assets/" cache-period="0" />
  <mvc:resources mapping="/img/**" location="/assets/${version}/img/"  cache-period="31556926" />
  <mvc:resources location="/assets/${version}/img/favicon.ico" mapping="/favicon.ico" />
```

The version variable is defined in application.properties and I am successfully using it in my JSP files. But I cant seem to use it when registering my static routes. Please Advice.

Comment: I think that Spring MVC has built in functionalities for resource cache busting. Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30139512/1291150) or [this one](https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/24/spring-framework-4-1-handling-static-web-resources) before trying to implement some custom solution. Disclaimer: I have not tried this personally, but it might help you. [This SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9204940/1291150) contains answer to your question (placeholders in mvc:resources) if you decide to go with custom solution. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks that sounds nice. Although I might still run with the custom solution if I get it to work as I like the idea of the app being delivered by version.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link to an article about static resources in spring, It explains very well this topic. In one part it talks about VersionResourceResolver, this resolver allows you to manage resource versions.

https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/24/spring-framework-4-1-handling-static-web-resources

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following syntax to capture the version string and map accordingly.

In the interceptor:

```
<mvc:interceptor>
  <mvc:mapping path="/assets/{version}}/**" />
  <bean id="webContentInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
    <property name="cacheSeconds" value="3600" />
    <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true" />
    <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true" />
    <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="false" />
  </bean>
 </mvc:interceptor>
```

In the resource mapping

```
 <mvc:resources mapping="/assets/{version}/**" location="/assets/" cache-period="0" />
```

The version brackets will capture any sub path to assets thus giving me the possibility to use version mapping just by putting a version after each asset in my jsp files.